# Validation the sum of multiple clone Input 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

Hey guys i'm trying to write a directive that could check the validation of multiple inputs fields which contain numbers as percentage. The directive should be able to check if the sum of all those inputs is 100.
So here is my HTML code :

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="form1" id="form1" method="post" novalidate>
 <input type="number" class="form-control" name="mtp" id="mtp" ng-model="mtp" placeholder="Percentage of the first main task" min="1" max="100" percentCheck required>
 <button class="btn btn-primary">Clone</button>  
</form>
```

This input is the original input field. I also wrote a js-function that clone this input everytime i click on the button. And it worked fine.
Here is my directive that i wrote to check the validation that i mentioned above

```
app.directive('percentCheck', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
        scope.$watch(attr.percentCheck, function(viewValue) {
            var sum = 0;
            angular.forEach(viewValue, function() {
                sum += parseInt($(this));
            });
            alert(sum);
            if (sum === 100) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }, true); //enable deep dirty checking
    }
}; });
```

And it doesnt work at all. Could anyone tell me where is the problems and give me some advices? Im just a newbie to this so i need a lot of helps. Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me. It's a slight modification of [angular: Validate multiple dependent fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18682384/angular-validate-multiple-dependent-fields). If it works for you, please don't forget to tick OK :-)

*Directive:* The directive will also through invalid if you enter e.g. characters instead of numbers.

```
        app.directive("validatePercentage", function () {

            return {

                restrict: "AE",

                require: "ngModel",

                link: function (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {

                    scope.$watch(attr["validatePercentage"], function (array) {

                        var sum = 0;
                        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                            sum = sum + parseInt(array[i].percentage);
                        }

                        if (sum === 100) {
                            ctrl.$setValidity("validatePercentage", true);
                        } else {
                            ctrl.$setValidity("validatePercentage", false);
                        }

                    }, true); 

                }

            };

        });
```

*Controller:* Add here as many fields as you need to check.

```
        $scope.itemsToCheck = [

            {"itemId": "1", "percentage": ""}, 
            {"itemId": "2", "percentage": ""}, 
            {"itemId": "3", "percentage": ""}

        ]
```

*HTML:*

```
        <form>
            <div ng-repeat="n in itemsToCheck>
                <input 
                    class="form-control" 
                    type="text" 
                    name="{{n.itemId}}" 
                    ng-model="n.percentage" 
                    validate-percentage="itemsToCheck"/>
            </div>
        </form>
```